# Is it possible to land a plane only with the Garmin® Synthetic Vision?

Tags: landing, glass-cockpit, g1000

A synthetic vision system shows the pilot the position of his plane in a 3D-modelled flight environment.

It's like a 3D TAWS. It also shows the position on the runway:

[image]

[image]

As I have seen, this feature works quite good. It's sometimes a bit off the centerline, but on the runway.

It is clearly stated that this is only to be used as feature to enhance the situational awareness. And I am also quite sure that this is not authorized as primary navigation source.

---

But imagine: You are flying in zero visibility. You have an emergency and must land. There is no ILS. (You have done no flight planning and the bad weather surprised you)

- Would it theoretically be possible to land a plane only with this synthetic vision?
- Is it accurate enough?
- Would the plane at least come down in one part?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently yes, according to [this 2008 review](http://www.planeandpilotmag.com/article/tech-talk-garmins-synthetic-vision-technology/#.WOfy4mkrJeM) of the system in a [Diamond DA40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_DA40):

> With [a safety pilot], I stayed under
>   the hood for the entire flight—takeoff, en route, approach and
>   landing—using the system’s visual cues. I managed to land the airplane
>   without breaking anything, barely. It wasn’t pretty, but it
>   demonstrated what was possible.